# Sql query for getting data where expiry date is after 60 days from the current data

Tags: mysql, sql

Sql query for getting data where expiry date is after 60 days from the current data.
the data format is

> date("y-m-d")

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: What you've done so far...?

Comment: we are using Mysql database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP using MySQL:

```
$date1 = date("y-m-d");
$date2 = date("y-m-d", strtotime("+ 60 day"));

$query=sprintf("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `date_column` > %s and `date_column` <= %s", $date1, $date2);
```

Answer (score 0):

oracle:

```
select * from table t where t.some_date between sysdate and (sysdate + 60);
```

format date:

```
to_date('2013-04-21','yyyy-mm-dd')
```